# My 3 months cat wants to explore living room but I'm afraid that I may let her out

Tags: cats, safety, adoption

I adopted yesterday a pair of 3 month kittens. I was told at shelter that I should confine them to one room for 7-14 days unless they start exploring. The most adventurous of sisters tried to repeatedly sneak past my legs when I enter or leave to get into living room. I'm a bit afraid they she will try to explore outside where catching her will be much more difficult. How can I prevent her from running away and getting lost when I exit my flat?

PS. I'm renting so I can't do too many things which are permanent.

**EDIT**: They are domestic shorthair and both are very sociable, playful and exploring (after letting them out of carrier they both started exploring with their tail in 'up' position). They both seems to have unlimited amounts of energy as well.

Comment: This sounds like my cats when we just adopted them. Although our cats learned to be 'afraid' of the entrance door opening because they can see neighbors going past (through the door window), and their fright mainly comes from their semi-feral state. While I don't know any valid solution and I'm not sure if your cats will gain an interest in the outside world, I'd recommend including some of their characteristics, such as breed, behaviour, etc etc. Sometimes the breed is important for a question such as this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) With experience, you will learn to check for cats underfoot before opening doors, and to position bags and such to help blockade unauthorized excursions.

2) If they are indoor- only cats, you may find that they will eventually decide that outdoors is Someone Else's Territory, and not actually be very interested in exploring it on their own. My girlfriend's cats, if carried outside, will generally dash right back inside. Mine will play sneak-past-me games at the inner door to the porch, but while they are interested in the outside I've never had them try to cross the outside threshold; they know they aren't supposed to do so.

3) Even if they are indoor- only cats, consider having them microchips.

Comment: Re 3). They are microchipped (by shelter but I would do it anyway) and have collars with my phone number. My  dads instincts are on the protective side.